# Where is the generic linux binary openjdk7.tar.gz?

Tags: java

Where can I get a vanilla tar.gz binary build download of openjdk7 for linux, similar to the oracle/sun vanilla jdk download?

Comment: The only alternatives I can find are [Oracle JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7u1-download-513651.html) or [IcedTea](http://icedtea.classpath.org/wiki/Main_Page#Getting_IcedTea).

Comment: How trying to download the Java Development Key this be "off-topic"

Surely its "software tools commonly used by programmers"

Nowadays getting Java devkits is non-trivial.

Comment: maybe here: https://github.com/ojdkbuild/contrib_jdk8u-ci/releases

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, such files do not exist. You can follow [these instructions](http://openjdk.java.net/install/) to install OpenJDK for Linux distributions that use DEB and RPM packages.

You could extract the files from the DEB (using [`dpkg-deb`](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkgtools.en.html#s-dpkg-deb) or [`ar`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ar)) or RPM (using `rpm2cpio` [[1]](http://linux.die.net/man/8/rpm2cpio) [[2]](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-miscellania-rpm2cpio.html) [[3]](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-extract-an-rpm-package-without-installing-it.html)) packages and create your own tarball.

Or, if you're up for the challenge, you can compile your own build using the [build instructions](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/raw-file/tip/README-builds.html). The nice thing about building your own is that you can create a [debug build](http://hiroshiyamauchi.blogspot.com/2008/07/build-openjdk.html) (Google does not return much information on debug builds, but you can look at the [Makefile](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/raw-file/14b8e7eee105/Makefile) for some information), which avails useful debugging options.

Answer (score 8):

You may find OpenJDK7 binaries for Linux (built on Debian Squeeze) in [openjdk-unofficial-builds](https://github.com/alexkasko/openjdk-unofficial-builds#openjdk-unofficial-installers-for-windows-linux-and-mac-os-x) github project. `*-image.zip` files contain plain archives of JDK without installers.

Disclaimer: I've built them myself

Edit: typo about macos

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll add disclaimers

Answer (score -3):

You can download/install OpenJDK 6 & 7 here http://openjdk.java.net/install/

You can download the latest source bundle here http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk7/

If you have mercurial you can even download the source for the pre-release Java 8. (however it may not be that different yet, except for more bugs perhaps ;)